# vbCrLF or Environment.NewLine

Tags: vb.net

I use Environment.NewLine, my colleagues use vbCrLf.

When I'm doing a code review for them I want something that I can point to to say "use Environment.NewLine instead of vbCrLf"

Or, am I just peeing in the wind, and it doesn't really matter ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Environment.NewLine is more portable, making to code easier to be read by someone coding in C#.  Technically vbCrLf is a constant, where NewLine is not.  This is because on a different OS, NewLine may not return CR/LF.  On Unix it would just be LF.

Answer (score 4):

Another point is that `Environment.NewLine` expresses the intended meaning more clearly. In most cases, the goal is *Place a newline in this string*, not *Place carriage-return and line-feed characters in this string*. `Environment.NewLine` states *what* to do, `vbCrlf` states *how* to do it.

Answer (score 3):

`Environment.NewLine` is portable in .NET and for someone unfamiliar with VB it is more readable than `vbCrLf`.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, either one will work correctly.

However, if you are developing on Mono and use Environment.NewLine on a Unix OS, then you will get different results (\n (LF) instead of \r\n (CRLF)).

In addition, if you ever want/need to port your code to C#, Environment.NewLine will not have to be updated whereas vbCrLf will.