# VB windows form calculate the digit in a multiline textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, multiline

I want to calculate each line: it's like first line 123*1.616 and the second line 213*1.616, and display each total.
Every number entred in the kilogram textbox will mutiply 1.616 and then show the result in the kati label.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub b1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b1.Enter

For Each digit In (TextBox1.Text)
            total1 = Val(digit) * 1.616
            Label9.Text = total1
        Next

        Label9.Text = total1
End sub
```

Please help me find some solution or explanation to achieve the output.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`. Possibly also `Option Explicit On`. And debug it. You'll *see*.

Comment: 1) The `Handles b1.Enter` should be `Handles b1.Click`. 2) To get each line of text from the TextBox, you can use `For Each line in TextBox1.Lines`. 3) It will be helpful to know that a *digit* is a single numeric character, like "3", so the number 123 has three digits.

Comment: Look at what @Andrew Morton states. Your code says `b1.Enter`. What is going on there? Also, what value are you expecting in the TextBox? An integer or something else?

Comment: i wish that each line in the kilogram textbox will mutiply 1.616 and display in the kati. Which mean the kati will have the answer of each line in kilogram textbox

Comment: @Hank. Yes we know that but that is not what these comments are asking you. Why do you have `b1.Enter` and what number format are you expecting in you Textbox? Whole numbers like 1,44,2076 or numbers like 1.23, 77.6, 144.8283, or a possibility of both?

Comment: @ Andrew Morton i changed but the kati label just show all the total after multiply,i wish to have 3total numbers just like the last picture,do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @video.baba i changed it to b1.click after i click the button convert to kati which is b1,the numbers in the kilogram,textbox will just have a number per line like 123.1  2.5 333

Comment: The more I look at this the more bizarre it gets.... You said multiple textbox by `1.616` and gave example of: `123,213,123` and example answer of: `4.848,16.11,4.848`. That is not the correct answer to the input values multiplying by `1.616`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Private FACTOR As Decimal = 1.616
Private SEPARATOR As String = Environment.NewLine

Private Sub b1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b1.Click
    Label9.Text = TextBox1.Text.
        Split({SEPARATOR}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
        Select(Function(s1) $"{Decimal.Parse(s1) * FACTOR:0.00#}").
        Aggregate(Function(s1, s2) $"{s1}{SEPARATOR}{s2}")
End Sub
```

Here are the functions in the LINQ

- `Split` makes an array out of each line in the TextBox using SEPARATOR as the delimiter
- `Select` transforms the elements into their value times FACTOR
- `Aggregate` puts the elements back together into a SEPERATOR delimited string

**Why didn't your original code work?**

- You were iterating over each char in the text, and multiplying the char by a float (`Option Strict On`, as suggested in the comments would have prevented that).
- Then in each iteration, you do (simplified) `Label9.Text = Val(digit) * 1.616` which overwrites the Label every time.
- If you were to step through in debug (also suggested in comments), you would see the Label becoming **1**x1.616=*1.616*, **2**x1.616=*3.232*, **3**x1.616=*4.848*, etc. The result was the very last *character* in your TextBox, '3', times 1.161 = 4.848. Obviously, this was not what you wanted. You needed to instead iterate over each entire number. The multiline TextBox separates each line with a new line. So we iterate over each *line* instead.

Answer (score -1):

you can use split string by vbCrLf

```
Sub main()


  Dim multilinetext As String =
    "10
     20
     30
     40
     50
     60"

    Dim number_array = multilinetext.Split(vbCrLf)
    Dim output As Integer = 0
    For Each i In number_array
        output += i
    Next
    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim multilinetext As String = TextBox1 had a error "cant convert textbox to string"

Comment: TextBox1 is a class that is a textbox, you need to access TextBox1.text to access the string of the textbox. Please remove the devote as it is invalid and you misunderstand how the code works.

Comment: ok thanks looks like the other guy is a professional troll thank you for the reply and good luck with your codding.

Comment: @MattheuNorwood I didn't downvote your answer. But it doesn't make any sense. Can you explain how this works? I'm not a "professional troll" (lol), I just wrote a working solution.

Comment: The split string function will delimit a string by a custom separator.   
dim string1 as string = "Hello,world,this,is,a,test"
and you wanted to create an array of the words and separate them by ","

 Dim word_array = string1.Split(",")

would give you an array that would yield an array with 6 elements with each element being a word.

in my example I use a similar approach which is using the vbCrLf
vbCrLf is the constant for a new line so if you separated a string by vbCrLf then it would give you an element for each line in the string.

Comment: Also if you are not the one that downvoted then I retract my statement about professional troll and apologize for my statement.

Comment: @MattheuNorwood I use `String.Split()` as well. Note that [Environment.NewLine is preferred over vbCrLf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930202/vbcrlf-or-environment-newline) - not really important. But you could also benefit from putting `Option Strict On` at the top of your code. `multilinetext.Split(vbCrLf)` creates a *string* array, then you iterate it `For Each i In number_array` and add each `i` (string) to `output` (Integer). OP would end up with a sum, however, since `output` is an Integer, he would lose the decimals in his example (and a sum was not needed anyway).

Comment: I figured he would understand the arithmetic example was just a proxy as it seemed his main problem was just trying to get each number separated by a new line.

Comment: @MattheuNorwood you may also want to look at [String.Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2). By passing `vbCrLf` you use the `Split(Char[])` overload because `vbCrLf` is two characters: Chr(13) & Chr(10). Doing this will split by the two characters together *and* each character individually. This would have strange results, for example `"babca".Split("abc") = {"b", "bc", ""}`. Using the `Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)` overload splits on the entire string: `"babca".Split({"abc"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) = {"b", "a"}`